# mvc3 dynamic report

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Using MVC3 and razor along with NuGet Doddle Report, I have built a nice report that opens a view model in Excel. I would like to allow the user to supply a filter and sort on the view before the report is exported to Excel. 
Are there recommended ways to do this or resources I could check out?

Thanks!

EDIT

Controller code that creates report:

```
public ReportResult CaseReport()
        {
        var viewModel = new CasesReportViewModel();


        var query = (from c in db.Cases
                     join customer in db.Customers on c.CustomerID equals customer.CustomerID
                     join category in db.CaseCategories on c.CaseCategoryID equals category.CaseCategoryID
                     join tech in db.Technicians on c.TechnicianID equals tech.TechnicianID
                     join engine in db.EngineModels on c.EngineModelID equals engine.EngineModelID
                     select new CasesReportViewModel()
                        {
                            CustomerName = c.Customer.CustomerName,
                            UserName = c.UserName,
                            PromoID = tech.PromoID,
                            EngineModelName = engine.EngineModelName,
                            CaseNumber = c.CaseNumber,
                            BMSWorkorder = c.BMSWorkorder,
                            CaseStatus = c.CaseStatus,
                            OpenedBy = c.OpenedBy,
                            OpenedDate = c.OpenedDate,
                            ClosedBy = c.ClosedBy,
                            ClosedDate = c.ClosedDate,
                            CategoryName = category.CategoryName,
                            CallerFirstName = c.CallerFirstName,
                            CallerLastName = c.CallerLastName,
                            AdditionalContact = c.AdditionalContact,
                            Qualified = c.Qualified,
                            Description = c.Description,
                            ESN = c.ESN,
                            Mileage = c.Mileage,
                            DateInService = c.DateInService,
                            ESTR = c.ESTR,
                            EDS = c.EDS
                        });


        var report = new Report(query.ToReportSource());

        //customize fields
        report.TextFields.Title = "Case Report";
        AppHelpers app = new AppHelpers();
        report.TextFields.Header = "Report Date = " + Convert.ToString(app.GetEasternTime());
        report.TextFields.Footer = "Copyright 2012";

        //data fields
        report.RenderHints.BooleanCheckboxes = true;

        report.DataFields["CustomerName"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["UserName"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["EngineModelName"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["CaseNumber"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["BMSWorkorder"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["CategoryName"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["CaseStatus"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["OpenedBy"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["OpenedDate"].DataFormatString = "{0:d}";
        report.DataFields["ClosedBy"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["ClosedDate"].DataFormatString = "{0:d}";
        report.DataFields["CallerFirstName"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["CallerLastName"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["AdditionalContact"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["Qualified"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["Description"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["ESN"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["Mileage"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["DateInService"].DataFormatString = "{0:d}";
        report.DataFields["ESTR"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";
        report.DataFields["EDS"].DataFormatString = "{0:c}";

        return new ReportResult(report, new ExcelReportWriter(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet") { FileName = "CaseReport" };

        }
```

Comment: Could you show some code? Code of controller that generate your report as example?

Comment: Kirill, I added the controller code. Thx

Comment: anyone know how I might work with this?